# Как лучше работать с бд? Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Пишу телеграмм бота, который будет работать с postgreSQL. Появился вопрос, как лучше получать данные? Нужно при запуске выгружать всю бд в словарь или когда нужно будет, сделать запрос?

Comment: Если вы будете хранить все данные в словаре, то тогда какой смысл использовать бд вообще?

Comment: Обычно запрашивают данные по запросу. Как правило в БД объем данных намного больше размера оперативной памяти сервера. Причин намного больше, но эта на поверхности

Comment: Понял, спасибо!